# How to fix issues with landscape layout in android?

Tags: android, layout, landscape-portrait

I am relatively new in android, and I have created a rather complex layout (with `AndroidStudio` 2.1.3; listed below), which works fine in the following cases:

- On a real phone in portrait mode (LG G3).
- In the `AndroidStudio` for Portrait mode
- In the `AndroidStudio` for Landscape mode

However, when I turn the real phone 90 degrees (real phone landscape mode), the layout is incorrect and looks like the following:

[image]

while the expected layout (as shown in `AndroidStudio`) is the follows:

[image]

When I hit the 'return' key on the phone, I see the expected layout, but as soon as I am about to enter data in any of the fields, the layout becomes incorrect.

How to fix the layout for the real phone?

See [the layout here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97de55cb8505e1e544e5a1a3aebca5a5) and here the `Manifest`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexander.inputlayoutscroll">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you need to have all your view in a linear or relative viewgroup and put that view group in a scroll view so that you can see all views via scrolling when keyboard shows up

Comment: do you want to run your app on Portrait as well  Landscape  mode ?   if you want only Portrait  mode than just put    android:screenOrientation="portrait"      in manifest file inside activtity tag    


Like <activity
            android:name="fffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

Comment: @sushantgosavi: I tried your suggestion, but I see no change of the app behavior.

Comment: @PavneetSingh: But why is it working in portrait mode? And why is the preview different from the actual layout in landscape mode?

Comment: @Alex i had a doubt about `next` button , see when orientation changes your activity is recreated so you need to go through your code and see what you are actually doing or simply to get quick help post your activity code and as suggested by sushant too use only portrait orientation to avoid activity recreation but this will make your app portrait mode only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it:

You can add this piece of code in your `EditText` views.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

OR

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
```

This will prevent the soft keyboard from popping up in full screen editing. Sometimes the first option doesn't work.

Else you can add this code in your activity in the `Manifest.xml` file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

You can get more help about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: Looks like the first suggestion actually works to solve the problem. Layout looks still like crap, but this is now for me to solve...

Comment: @Alex Well, glad to help. Certainly the layout is on you to modify now.